# Error while building U-boot

Tags: embedded, arm, cross-compiling, linux-toolchain

I am building u-boot for A13-olinuxino. I have downloaded the arm toolchain.
But while building i get this following *error*.

```
root@vinuthan-pc:/home/vinuthan/Documents/u-boot-sunxi-sunxi# make a13_olinuxino CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
/bin/bash: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: So what happens when you type in "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" at the command line?

Comment: Thank you, figured it out when i typed it. Hadn't installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Had missed out on it when i installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, figured it out when i typed it. Hadn't installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Had missed out on it when i installed arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.7.